# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick in android

Tags: java, android, textview

I am fairly new to Android and creating my first app. I am using using following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int netScore = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void addOne(View view) {
   netScore = netScore + 1;
    displayScore(netScore);
}

private void displayScore(int printScore) {
    TextView varScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    varScore.setText(printScore);
}

}
```

When I click the button, it throws this error in debug:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Does anybody have an idea about this error?

Comment: where is your code for onclick button and where you bind button??

Comment: Yes I am using it as:

<Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                android:paddingTop="24dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:onClick="addOne"/>

Comment: Post your full code

Comment: Thanks for the help. This worked for me:

varScore.setText(String.valueOf(printScore))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did try adding the onClick in the xml-layout like this?

```
android:onClick="method"
```

If so, make sure that there are no typos.
In your case it would probably be:

```
android:onClick="addOne"
```

You can also listen for the click events programmatically. Check out [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html).

Comment: Yes I am using it as:

<Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                android:paddingTop="24dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:onClick="addOne"/>

Comment: try varScore.setText(""+printScore);

Comment: Or a better option would be varScore.setText(String.valueOf(printScore))

Comment: Thanks. This worked:

varScore.setText(String.valueOf(printScore))

Answer (score 0):

You can set the TextView in OnCreate method:

```
TextView varScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
```

after that add the ClickListener to the **varScore**:

```
enter code here
varScope.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         // do anything whatever you want
    }
});
```

At first, try to initiate the **TextView** in the **onCreate** method.

BTW could you please show us your .xml file?