# App crashing when i hit a button that calls a function i made

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Ok, so I Am making a movie app and while doing so I came across this problem. I Have this function which when pressed will print out titles of some movies but when I try to run it I get this error message I'm getting the movies using TMDB API.
If you know how to fix it please tell me, Thanks!

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing either @GET URL or @Url parameter.
        for method MovieApi.searchMovie
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:43)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:210)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:67)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:26)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy1.searchMovie(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.watchitmovieapp.MainActivity.GetRetrofitResponse(MainActivity.java:44)
        at com.example.watchitmovieapp.MainActivity.onButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:37)
```

Here is my code
**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.watchitmovieapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.watchitmovieapp.models.MovieModel;
import com.example.watchitmovieapp.request.Servicey;
import com.example.watchitmovieapp.response.MovieSearchResponse;
import com.example.watchitmovieapp.utils.Credentials;
import com.example.watchitmovieapp.utils.MovieApi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);

    }

    public void onButtonClicked(View view){
        GetRetrofitResponse();
    }

    private void GetRetrofitResponse() {
        MovieApi movieApi = Servicey.getMovieApi();

        Call<MovieSearchResponse> responseCall = movieApi
                .searchMovie(
                        Credentials.API_KEY,
                        "Jack Reacher",
                        "1");
        responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<MovieSearchResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieSearchResponse> call, Response<MovieSearchResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200){
                    //Log.v("Tag", "The response" + response.body().toString());

                    List<MovieModel> movies = new ArrayList<>(response.body().getMovies());

                    for (MovieModel movie: movies){
                        Log.v("Tag", "Name" + movie.getTitle());
                    }
                }else{
                    try {
                        Log.v("Tag", "Error" + response.errorBody().string());
                    }catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieSearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Servicey**

```
package com.example.watchitmovieapp.request;

import com.example.watchitmovieapp.utils.Credentials;
import com.example.watchitmovieapp.utils.MovieApi;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public class Servicey {
    private static Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Credentials.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = retrofitBuilder.build();

    private static  MovieApi movieApi = retrofit.create(MovieApi.class);

    public static MovieApi getMovieApi(){
        return movieApi;
    }

}
```

**MovieSearchResponse**

```
package com.example.watchitmovieapp.response;

import com.example.watchitmovieapp.models.MovieModel;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class MovieSearchResponse {
    @SerializedName("total_results")
    @Expose()
    private int total_count;
    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose()
    private List<MovieModel> movies;
    public int getTotal_count(){
        return total_count;
    }
    public List<MovieModel> getMovies(){
        return movies;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MovieSearchResponse{" +
                "total_count=" + total_count +
                ", movies=" + movies +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**MovieApi**

```
package com.example.watchitmovieapp.utils;

import android.graphics.Movie;

import com.example.watchitmovieapp.response.MovieSearchResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface MovieApi {

    // searching
    @GET
    Call<MovieSearchResponse> searchMovie(
            @Query("key") String key,
            @Query("query") String query,
            @Query("page") String page
    );
}
```

**Movie Model**

```
package com.example.watchitmovieapp.models;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MovieModel implements Parcelable  {

    private String title;
    private String poster_path;
    private String release_date;
    private int movie_id;
    private float vote_average;
    private String movie_overview;

    //Constructor


    public MovieModel(String title, String poster_path, String release_date, int movie_id, float vote_average, String movie_overview) {
        this.title = title;
        this.poster_path = poster_path;
        this.release_date = release_date;
        this.movie_id = movie_id;
        this.vote_average = vote_average;
        this.movie_overview = movie_overview;
    }

    //Getters

    protected MovieModel(Parcel in) {
        title = in.readString();
        poster_path = in.readString();
        release_date = in.readString();
        movie_id = in.readInt();
        vote_average = in.readFloat();
        movie_overview = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<MovieModel> CREATOR = new Creator<MovieModel>() {
        @Override
        public MovieModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MovieModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MovieModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MovieModel[size];
        }
    };

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getPoster_path() {
        return poster_path;
    }

    public String getRelease_date() {
        return release_date;
    }

    public int getMovie_id() {
        return movie_id;
    }

    public float getVote_average() {
        return vote_average;
    }

    public String getMovie_overview() {
        return movie_overview;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(title);
        parcel.writeString(poster_path);
        parcel.writeString(release_date);
        parcel.writeInt(movie_id);
        parcel.writeFloat(vote_average);
        parcel.writeString(movie_overview);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Missing either @GET URL or @Url parameter.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196392/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-execute-method-for-androidonclick-in)

Comment: @BroscR No, see a_local_nobody's comment for the actual error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing URL(Request destination path) after `@GET` in your`searchMovie()` method in `MovieApi interface`

Example:
`@GET("api/fruit/all")`